# accepting request to connect on DB port only from a DNS

Tags: server, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to add an INPUT rule to my server so that only specific address can connect to my DB.
So far I tried this
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m string --string dnsname.com --algo bm  --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT`
it does not work as I cannot connect to the db
I think it's because I'm missing the -s parameter but I think it is only for IP address isn't it? Can you put a dns into it?